# Is there any way to make a double-input-prompt box in javascript? (With Example)

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When you go to this site: ***https://www.w3.org/2002/***

It asks you to enter a username and password (both in one prompt box).

This box is just a default browser prompt box but with two input fields.

I have searched for many resources to make something like that but I didn't get the answer.

Comment: It's a server-side authentication passed in the response headers, you can't call that prompt box in JS.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript, this is the popup browsers present to ask you for your credentials for _HTTP Authentication_.

Comment: You can of course create any kind of form with two input boxes you like in HTML, then then show it as a _modal_ using Javascript.